# Sharing Image with Intent - Android 4.4

Tags: android, sharing, android-4.4-kitkat

I have got a Problem here. My Sharing Function works with 4.0.4, 4.3, and so on.

But with 4.4.2 nothing works at all.

The Text can be shared, thats no Problem but the Picture can not be shared with Gmail or MMS. But Dropbox for Example is Working. Anyone have an idea?

Here My sharing code:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "...");
String textBody = "..";
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textBody);
sharingIntent.putExtra("sms_body", textBody);

sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
File cachedImage = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().get(currentSong.imgurl);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachedImage));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

I am using an Image out of the Universal Image Loader. Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Found out that the OS Version is not important. HTC Wildfire S with 4.0.4 works pretty good. Samsung R with 4.0.4 doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer myself: You have to store the Image in the MediaStore.